# "Fare nulla" vs."Non fare nulla" in una frase particolare: significati diversi?

Tags: meaning, negation

> - Sì, ma non si può non riconoscere che quel governo fece nulla sul piano dei privilegi, però.
> - Sì, ma non si può non riconoscere che quel governo ***non*** fece nulla sul piano dei privilegi, però.

Secondo voi le frasi di cui sopra hanno significati diversi?

Se non li hanno, come si spiega che l'aggiunta o l'omissione di quel 'non', rispettivamente nella seconda o nella prima, non produca alcun effetto semantico?

Comment: Già il *non si può non riconoscere* è da evitare; se risparmi parole e dici *quel governo non fece nulla riguardo ai privilegi* o *quel governo nulla fece riguardo ai privilegi* non avrai più il dubbio.

Answer (score 2):

Secondo la [Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/negazione_(Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano)/), la forma che omette il "non", cioè la frase

> Sì, ma non si può non riconoscere che quel governo fece nulla sul piano dei privilegi, però

viene usata in diverse varietà colloquiali, soprattutto settentrionali, e non ha nessuna differenza semantica rispetto all'altra forma. Nell'italiano più formale o standard

> la presenza o assenza di *non* con un secondo elemento negativo (*nessuno*, *mai*, *mica*, ecc.) è regolata da queste due restrizioni:
>
> (a) se gli elementi negativi seguono il verbo, il *non* è obbligatorio:
>
> *non lo sapevo mica*
>
> *non mi dice mai niente nessuno*
>
> (b) se gli elementi negativi precedono il verbo, il *non* è escluso:
>
> *mica lo sapevo*
>
> *nessuno mi dice mai niente*

La Treccani riporta questi esempi di omissione di "non" in frasi con elementi negativi postverbali in diverse varietà colloquiali

> *siamo mica matti*
>
> *c’era nessuno*
>
> *fa niente*

e afferma:

> Queste costruzioni possono riflettere il sostrato dialettale a negazione postverbale di alcuni dialetti gallo-italici: *sta fomna la m pyaz mia* «questa donna non mi piace» (lomb. orientale).

Dunque, si può concludere che la frase

> Sì, ma non si può non riconoscere che quel governo ***non*** fece nulla sul piano dei privilegi, però

è italiano standard, mentre la frase

> Sì, ma non si può non riconoscere che quel governo fece nulla sul piano dei privilegi, però

è più colloquiale.

Comment: Devo ammettere che, pur essendo del Nord e conoscendo la parlata colloquiale, la frase "Sì, ma non si può non riconoscere che quel governo fece nulla sul piano dei privilegi, però" mi suona strana. Nella lingua colloquiale si direbbe piuttosto "non han fatto niente"; solo nel dialetto si ometterebbe il "non" (es. in dialetto lombardo, g'à fat nient).

Comment: Potrebbe darsi una contaminazione di registri linguistici nella frase "Sì, ma non si può non riconoscere che quel governo fece nulla sul piano dei privilegi, però"? Cioè, la Treccani afferma che l'omissione di "non" in frasi con elementi negativi postverbali è caratteristica di diverse varietà colloquiali, ma a @GiulioMuscarello questa frase suona strana.

Answer (score 1):

If in English and German double negation makes the sentence affirmative in Italian it is not always true. 
So, for example, a good translation for the sentence "I have nothing" is "Non ho nulla"; but the sentence "I do not have nothing" cannot be translated into "Non ho nulla" since it would be misunderstood by many, and it is preferably to translate it into "Ho qualcosa".

Back to your question the sentences are both correct, but I would prefer

> Sì, ma non si può non riconoscere che quel governo non fece nulla sul
>   piano dei privilegi, però.

since it would be the most used.